Ubuntu - dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -d - Gives me error - Need some pointers to understand this and resolve it
I am in the process of configuring Squid Proxy over https
On the same line I found this link on YouTube that help configure Squid over https -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bogdplu_lsE
While trying the steps I am stuck at this point
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -d
Error -
configure: exit 1
dh_auto_configure: error: ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=\${prefix}/include --mandir=\${prefix}/share/man --infodir=\${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-option-checking --disable-silent-rules --libdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking "BUILDCXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer -ffile-prefix-map=/squid-5.7=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fcf-protection -fdebug-prefix-map=/squid-5.7=/usr/src/squid-5.7-1ubuntu3 -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=3 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now " BUILDCXX=g\+\+ --with-build-environment=default "--enable-build-info=Ubuntu linux" --datadir=/usr/share/squid --sysconfdir=/etc/squid --libexecdir=/usr/lib/squid --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-inline --disable-arch-native --enable-async-io=8 --enable-storeio=ufs,aufs,diskd,rock --enable-removal-policies=lru,heap --enable-delay-pools --enable-cache-digests --enable-icap-client --enable-follow-x-forwarded-for --enable-auth-basic=DB,fake,getpwnam,LDAP,NCSA,PAM,POP3,RADIUS,SASL,SMB --enable-auth-digest=file,LDAP --enable-auth-negotiate=kerberos,wrapper --enable-auth-ntlm=fake,SMB_LM --enable-external-acl-helpers=file_userip,kerberos_ldap_group,LDAP_group,session,SQL_session,time_quota,unix_group,wbinfo_group --enable-security-cert-validators=fake --enable-storeid-rewrite-helpers=file --enable-url-rewrite-helpers=fake --enable-eui --enable-esi --enable-icmp --enable-zph-qos --enable-ecap --enable-ssl --enable-ssl-crtd --with-openssl --disable-translation --with-swapdir=/var/spool/squid --with-logdir=/var/log/squid --with-pidfile=/run/squid.pid --with-filedescriptors=65536 --with-large-files --with-default-user=proxy --enable-linux-netfilter --with-systemd --with-gnutls returned exit code 1
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:85: override_dh_auto_configure] Error 255
make[1]: Leaving directory '/squid-5.7'
make: *** [debian/rules:77: build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2
root@ip-172-31-69-18:/squid-5.7#


Snippet from debian/rules where the above lines might be indicating looks like this (line 77 and line 85)
%:
        dh $@

override_dh_auto_configure:
        mkdir -p debian/build-openssl
        # copy the source to build-openssl
        tar -cf - --exclude=debian/build* --exclude=.pc . \
                | tar -xf - -C debian/build-openssl
        # run buildconf and make sure to copy the patched ltmain.sh
        #for flavour in build build-gnutls build-nss; do \
        #       (cd debian/$$flavour && ./buildconf && cp ../../ltmain.sh .) \
        #done
        dh_auto_configure -- ${DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS} \
                --with-gnutls
        cd debian/build-openssl && dh_auto_configure -- ${DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS} \
                --with-openssl \
                --enable-ssl-crtd


